# Adding truncated line to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot decision boundaries of a decision tree in `ggplot`. Unfortunately, when I run this code, I partition `data_plot` into four (rather than three regions). Note that below data is just a placeholder (doesn't make sense to partition this way).

```
data_plot <- data.frame(x=runif(100,0,1), y=runif(100,0,1))
cut1 <- 0.5
cut2 <- 0.5

ggplot(data_plot, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = cut1) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = cut2)
```

[image: Example]

**Question:** How can I restrict the second cut to one of the intervals induced by the first cut. That is, how can I truncate the second line to the interval [cut1, 1] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could use `geom_segment` like this:

```r
data_plot <- data.frame(x=runif(100,0,1), y=runif(100,0,1))
cut1 <- 0.5
cut2 <- 0.5

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data_plot, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = cut1) + 
  geom_segment(x = cut2, xend = 1, y = cut2, yend = cut2, size = 0.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I knew there must be some function to do this in a nice way!